# XML document structures must start and end within the same entity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

What is the problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.4" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".MainActivity"
            tools:ignore="IntentFilterExportedReceiver">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">

                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the closing `</manifest>` tag under the `</application>`:

```
   (...)
   </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What should i do ????       Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for <receiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: @Mohammed That is another error rising. Normally, you need to add `android:exported="true"` in the `<receiver>` tag.

Comment: Still have more problems          AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_launcher (aka com.example.4:drawable/ic_launcher) not found.

Comment: @Mohammed `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` may mistake of `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`.

Answer (score 0):

Close the manifest tag after application tag.

`</application></manifest>`

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  // check in drawable folder under res whether the default image ic_launcher is present or not. That is the default icon for your application.
```

Comment: Its keep adding more errors like this one-----  Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found
Error while Launching activity

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `</manifest>` on the last line. It's also likely that `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` should be changed to `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.4" >

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```